delete the table entry based on numeric range
I am trying to delete the entries in a table where the condition is numeric range.
delete from customer where id in [5,25);

Message: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
Kindly help me solve this issue
delete the entries with id of the range

I assume that your range includes the lower bound 5 and excludes the upper bound 25. Then delete from customer where id <@ numrange(5,25, '[)');. Documentation on range types is here

If you want to delete the entry based on numeric range you can use BETWEEN
DELETE FROM customer 
WHERE id BETWEEN 5 AND 25;

